# Can't wrap my head around how to get any useful output from fuser

Tags: fuser

```
cd ~
touch test
fuser -v -m test
```

Outputs pretty much all processes on my system, including e.g. `chromium`. Isn't `fuser` supposed to be showing only the processes that use the file? I tried it on my Manjaro desktop and on a CentOS server, to the same result of a huge number of processes "using" a freshly created file.

Answer (score 2):

READ the manual page for fuser !

Either way, if it is a current linux system (manjaro is that if i understand correctly) : basically all files is in the same filesystem.

The '-m' flag to fuser means : include all processes which uses a file in the same filesystem as in your example the 'test' file.

Don't use '-m' flag in this case.
The '-m' flag is useful if you have multiple smaller filesystem and you want to for example unmount and remove a filesystem. Then it becomes necessary to track which processes uses files/directories in that system.